# jQuery AJAX call sending as OPTIONS and missing Authorization header

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, http

I'm starting to get stumped on this. I'm developing a C#.NET Web API service and frontend application to use it. I've been having a lot of difficulty using a token to authenticate my requests and jQuery seems to be having trouble. I can get a token just fine, but jQuery won't add it to an Authorization header in further requests.

My setup is an index.html page with several jQuery Mobile pages inside it. It starts on a '#login' page, which sends a request to my /Token URI with a username, password, and grant type. This is successful and the return is the token. The page changes to '#home' and a test ajax call is sent to /api/values to grab value. The problem is that instead of adding a header called 'Authorization', jQuery adds an 'Access-Control-Request-Headers' with the value 'accept, authorization' instead. At first I thought it was a CORS issue, but the request works fine when I use Advanced Rest Client in Chrome to send the request.

AJAX Call from '#Home'

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://slalomtest2.azurewebsites.net/api/values/',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        dataType:"json",
        beforeSend: function(request){
            request.withCredentials = true;
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Token);
        },
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(request, error){
            $.mobile.changePage("#login");
        }
    });
```

[The bad request the AJAX sends](http://i103.photobucket.com/albums/m145/Mandalore65/Capture.png)

[This is what it looks like from Advanced Rest Client in the same browser](http://i103.photobucket.com/albums/m145/Mandalore65/Capture2.png)

Thanks in advance for the help, I've been banging my head against the wall all day.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not use forms authentication?

Comment: This is going to be a Phonegap Mobile app, so we need to use Token Authentication

Comment: Maybe try to uppercase first letter in "bearer" (RFC6750: credentials = "Bearer" 1*SP b64token)

Comment: Just tried uppercase and lowercase. Also just realized I had a typo with 'Basic' instead of 'Bearer' but it didn't change anything

Comment: On second screen shot I see you use Bearer authentication, but in the code here is Basic Auth. Make sure you use proper syntax for bearer auth,  not "Basic Bearer b64Token".

instead of request.setRequestHeader() u can always use header property to send: 

headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + bearerToken
    }

Comment: @MagyaDEV , just fixed the basic and changed it to 'bearer' but it isn't changing the problem. What seems to be happening is jQuery won't add the authorization header, and I've tried both ways - the way you mentioned and the way above. Oddly enough, when I try to specify content-type, the header also adds that to the list of Access-Control-Request-Headers